# How can I translate an array using a hash?

Tags: ruby

What I'm trying to do is giving a list of columns, get an array of column formats.  I have an array of column names, and a has where the key is the column name and the value is the format the column needs.  If there's no value in the hash for a given column, it needs to be nil in the resulting array.

Given:

```
  report_columns = ["val1", "val2", "subtotal", 
                    "othertotal", "grand_total", "moar_total"]
  column_formats = {"grand_total"   => @highlight_money,
                    "subtotal"  => @money}
```

I can easily do it with this code:

```
  datatype_array = []
  report_columns.each {|col| datatype_array << column_formats[col] }
  # do stuff with datatype_array
```

But this is ruby.  There's a more concise way to do this!  Please let me know what magic method I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're first attempt should be a simple `map` rather than an `each` that accumulates onto an array.

```
datatype_array = report_columns.map { |c| column_formats[c] }
```

You can also splat the array of columns into `Hash#values_at`, which expects multiple key names as individual arguments:

```
datatype_array = column_formats.values_at(*report_columns)
```

Comment: I don't see room for improvement or even a close second.

Comment: FWIW Ruby 2.3 has `Hash#to_proc` so you can do `report_columns.map(&column_formats)`.

Comment: And without `Hash#to_proc`, you can do `report_columns.map(&column_formats.method(:[]))`